# Gridview click on row enable controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rowdatabound

I have a gridview. The gridview has a textbox multiline that keeps an text.  After that I have a column with imagebutton named approved, and one named not approved. I want to force the user before click approved or not approved to read the text inside the multiline box. How can I achieve this programmatically? I know I should create a Rowdatabound Event, but what I should do with the code? I am using c# ASP.NET web application.

Comment: its not `rowdatabound` event

Comment: Add jscript to button, which enables input to multiline box.

Comment: I believe it is rowdatabound,  because  what I want is: when the user clicks on the specific row the two image buttons, in this row, will be enabled. Otherwise the image buttons will be disabled.

Comment: how can you force a user to read the text ?

Comment: I assume that if the user clicks on the row gives interest  to the selected text. Maybe I am wrong but this is the closest to what I want to achieve. Can you help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you can track the scroll bar of the browser using javascript but I've personally never come across similar functionality for a text box. I would suggest trying a slightly different approach, why don't you add an extra column to you grid view which has a check box control for -  **I've read and accepted the agreement**. And the Approve button will only be enabledd when the checkbox is checked, here's an example:

**ASPX:**

```
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="grid_RowDataBound">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" ID="txtAgreement" Text='<%# Eval("Agreement") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            I have read and accepted the agreement
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAgreement" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckedChanged" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAccept" runat="server" Text="Accept" OnClick="Accept" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            var items = new List<License> { new License { Agreement = "Agreement 1" }, new License { Agreement = "Agreement 2" } };
            grid.DataSource = items;
            grid.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void Accept(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            (e.Row.FindControl("btnAccept") as Button).Enabled = false;
    }

    protected void CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var chkAgreement = sender as CheckBox;
        Button btnAccept = null;

        if (chkAgreement != null)
        {
            var row = chkAgreement.Parent.Parent as GridViewRow;
            btnAccept = row.FindControl("btnAccept") as Button;

            if (btnAccept != null)
                if (chkAgreement.Checked)
                    btnAccept.Enabled = true;
                else
                    btnAccept.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}

public class License
{
    public string Agreement { get; set; }
}
```